# How to build a jar/aar with dependencies in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I had a project library in android studio with following dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])//Local binary dependency
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'//Remote binary dependency
api group: 'com.google.collections', name: 'google-collections', version: '1.0'
```

My question is how to build a jar/aar with dependencies? 
I have tried many ways but it did not including "google-collections" dependency in exported jar/aar?

how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have local dependencies, you should put on your `libs` folder and add your dependencies. But if you have remote libraries, you should add your main project's gradle your library's, too. I guess, Google docs say that.

Comment: @AytekSökmen - Yes I have remote libraries and i want to add them in my jar/aar. Can you explain how to add main project's gradle my library's?

Comment: For example in my project that has library project, my library project has a few libraries eventbus, butterknife etc.. I added eventbus, butterknife and the others to my main project's gradle and it worked by this way.

Comment: @AytekSökmen -  It means we can not add remote libraries direct to exported jar/aar and it should be added to the project's gradle where exported jar/aar is in use.

Comment: Actually they should be added your main and library projects both.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @AytekSökmen